# Eight distinct numbers in the table

Tags: mathematics, combinatorics

While I was working on [Ten distinct numbers in the table](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/22942/ten-distinct-numbers-in-the-table), [I found](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/22962/1955) that odd-sized tables will all work. Additionally, the technique [@xnor used](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/22943/1955) to prove a 10x10 doesn't work does not automatically rule out 4x4 and 8x8 tables from working. A 4x4 table doesn't work, but what about an 8x8 table?

|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 |
| 7 | 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 |
| 6 | 7 | 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 |
| 5 | 6 | 7 | 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 |
| 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 |
| 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 0 | 1 | 2 |
| 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 0 | 1 |
| 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 0 |

Same rules as before - can you pick the numbers 0 through 7 such that you have one of each number, with every column and row being represented exactly once each?

If this doesn't work, are there any even-sized tables that do? If it does, is there a general rule for which ones work and which don't?

<sub>Parity check: 0-7 add up to 28, so numbers+rows+columns adds up to 84. Even number passes the parity check.</sub>

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is impossible for an $n\times n$ table whenever $n$ is even.

If we number the rows $0,1,\ldots,n-1$ and the columns similarly, the entry in row $i$, column $j$ is congruent to $j-i$ modulo $n$. It follows that if we pick $n$ entries, one from each row and column, the sum of these entries must be divisible by $n$ (modulo $n$, each number $0,1,\ldots,n-1$ gets added once as a column number and subtracted once as a row number). So if it is possible to pick our $n$ numbers to be $0,1,\ldots,n-1$, is must be the case that $0+1+\ldots+(n-1)$ is divisible by $n$. We can compute
$$
0+1+\ldots+(n-1)=n\frac{n-1}{2}.
$$
This sum is divisible by $n$ if and only if $(n-1)/2$ is an integer, i.e. if and only if $n$ is odd.

Comment: Very nice reasoning!